# Niagara AX 3.8.38 Compile error: The import "java/sql/DriverManager" is not valid

Tags: java, sql

I want to create a module for Niagara AX 3.8.38, but once I import the java.sql.DriverManager, the following error happened:

> Semantic Error: The import "java/sql/DriverManager" is not valid, since it does not name a type in a package.

I can find the DriverManager class is in the "Niagara-3.8.38\jre\lib\rt.jar" and the Connection, Statement class can be imported correctly.

The other error is:

> Semantic Error: No accessible method with signature "contains(java.lang.String)" was found in type "java.lang.String".

The source code is "if (source.contains(slotPath))" and the source is a String object.

How should I solve these problems?

Does the rt.jar of Niagara 3.8.38 is right?

In addition, is there some difference between WorkBench and WorkPlace?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved:
https://www.niagara-community.com/Comm_ChatterAnswers?id=906D0000000TZj2IAG

The result is I didn't configure the Niagara AX correctly.